# Will Windows 10 applications work in Windows Phone 8.1?

Tags: windows, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, windows-8.1, windows-10

I'm thinking about developing applications for Windows platform. I want to start with Windows 10 as it is a future platform.

If I develop an app targeting Windows 10 will it work in Windows 8.1 & Windows Phone 8.1 ?

Comment: It is already much more complicated than that. There are Silverlight 8 apps, Silverlight 8.1 apps, Universal apps. And all of them have differents peculiarities (limitations)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what i did when i saw windows 10 coming. I read a few articles saying its not a good idea to have Silverlight project when Win10 comes to market. So,

1. Ported my Silverlight project to Universal App(windows 8.1, windows phone 8.1)
2. Modularized my solution completely so that only UI related code existed on my UI projects and all the business logic are in Runtime components.

With minimal effort i am going to port my universal project to win 10. In fact, last week i installed win10 on my machine with vs2015 and even compiled the whole code and deployed it on my phones(Windows phone8.1 and Win10). Worked like a charm.

So essentially the suggestion is if you want to cater to wp/w8.1 then the best idea is to develop as a part of 8.1 sdk and so that it will work on 10. And when 8.1 fades away from the market, it is way to simpler for you to port it to win10.

Answer (score 6):

No, you will have to find the lowest common denominator for the platforms you want to support

Comment: Windows 10 is a WinRT platform so are Windows 8.1 & Wp8.1. Why isn't that possible then..? (I admit there are many new APIs in Windows 10 then wp and win 8.1, but except those new APIs, other apps should work..!)

Comment: I guess Windows 10 being single OS for all the screens would make it difficult to run on older versions becuase they are using AdaptiveLayout like features which might not be recognized in older versions.

Answer (score 1):

Windows phone 8.1 does not support the universal Windows application platform, which is what Windows 10 apps target.

You can make use of the existing Universal apps for Windows 8.1 apps model which will allow you to target Windows 8.1 Store and Windows phone 8.1. That codebase will be very easy to rebuild as a Windows 10 app as well.